# Python. Regular Expression: "выбросить" текст между символами

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст: `h1;some text in h1;h1`. Как с помощью `re` вытащить `h1;` до и после текста?

**Из комментариев:**
Нужно получить значения h1. Но вместо h1 могут быть другие символы.
То есть, просто нужно "выбросить" текст между этими символами.

Comment: Что значит "вытащить"? Убрать? Заменить? Получить значения?

Comment: нужно детальнее расписать. Вытащить то, что и так известно нет смысла.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Да, получить значения __h1__. Но вместо __h1__ могут быть другие символы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev То есть, просто нужно "выбросив" текст между этими символами.

Comment: может ли `some text in h1` содержать `;` внутри?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если текст между символами ';' надо просто выбросить, то решение элементарное

```
import re
re.sub(r';.*;', ';;', 'h1;some text in h1;h1')
```

Comment: В условии было написано, что вместо *h1* могут быть и другие символы (к примеру: p1, d1, z1).

Comment: И приведённый мной пример будет их обрабатывать, можете проверить. Функция `re.sub` первым параметром принимает регулярное выражение, вторым подстановочное, а третьим строку, которую требуется обработать.

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/nG8wH9/2

```
import re
re.sub(r'([\w\d]+;)(.*?)\1', r'\1\1', 'h1;some text in h1;h1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение будет такое:

```
start_h, _, end_h = line_for_parse.split(';')
assert start_h == end_h
```